# Мнения о "Грамматике Пор-Рояля"

Tags: грамматика

Пожалуйста, расскажите о том, как оценивают современные филологи "Общую и рациональную грамматику", изданную аббатами монастыря Пор-Рояль в 1660 году?

Comment: Вопрос скорее о филологии вообще, чем о русском языке, т.е. не по теме сайта.

Answer (score 0):

Как сердцу высказать себя? Другому как понять тебя? Поймет ли он, чем ты живешь? Мысль изреченная есть ложь (Ф. Тютчев).

"Суха, мой друг, теория, везде, Но древо жизни пышно зеленеет" (Гёте).

ДЛЯ СПРАВОК. "Рациональная грамматика,  называемая еще «философской грамматикой», противопоставлялась описательным и нормативным грамматикам и получила в 17—19 вв. широкое распространение в логике и лингвистике. Согласно этой теории, людям присуща единообразная мыслительная и речевая способность, в основе всех языков лежит единая идеальная логическая схема, но ни один конкретный язык не тождествен этому потенциально данному человеческому языку".

Реальный язык  с его конкретной грамматикой - это неиссякаемый источник логических ошибок. Ну не может форма идеально выразить содержание, поэтому надо стараться продвинуть ее к рациональности и логичности. Возьмите любое суждение, и вы увидите, как  много в нем неясностей, вторых, третьих, а то и вовсе скрытых смыслов. Структура мысли едина, и только не согласованная с разумом грамматика препятствует нашему взаимопониманию. Так почему мы должны терпеть это грамматическое несовершенство! Кто виноват - ясно, теперь бы догадаться, что делать.

В современных грамматических учебниках (на разных уровнях) значительно больше внимания уделяется точности соответствия семантики и синтаксиса, то есть рассматривается синонимия форм для выражения одного содержания. Таким образом, обнаруживается какая-то связь с идеей рациональных грамматиков, которые, к примеру, рассуждали  о  СИНОНИМИИ  языковых выражений, из которых одно признается более соответствующим логике ,  а   другое   может употребляться вместо него ради  «желания  людей  сократить  речь»  или  «для изящества  речи».

Comment: Прочитал про "реальный язык с его конкретной грамматикой" как "неиссякаемый источник логических ошибок".

P.S. Я стараюсь не путать речь (например, пользователя русского языка, который величает себя behemothus'ом) и язык (например, русский язык).